# Get the total no of records returned from the API

Tags: jquery-bootgrid

I'm getting the data for the grid using an API. The api is returning the data in the below format

```
{
  "current": 1,
  "rowCount": 10,
  "rows": [
    {
      "id": 19,
      "sender": "123@test.de",
      "received": "2014-05-30T22:15:00"
    },
    {
      "id": 14,
      "sender": "123@test.de",
      "received": "2014-05-30T20:15:00"
    },
    ...
  ],
  "total": 1123
}
```

My question is, is it possible the to send back the "total" to the API when the user clicks on next page or search or any other operation?. Basically I want to send the total after the first time data loaded to the grid.

```
ajax: true,
post: function ()
{
    /* To accumulate custom parameter with the request object */
    return {
ReportID: "[ReportID]"
,Parameters:"[ReportParameters:Json]"
     ,RecordsPerPage:ReportOption.pageSize
     ,Key:drillThroughKey
     **,Total:{total}**
    };
}
```

In the above code {total} needs to be the total received at the first time.

Thanks